# What did Aristotle and Plato think of each other?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, aristotle, plato

Since Plato was a teacher of Aristotle and was living until Aristotle was 36 years old I was wondering of what kind of opinion Aristotle had of Plato's personality and work and vice versa

Comment: Aristotle's works are full of comments about Plato's thinking: we may say that a relevant part of A's philosophical work is a critique of the basic Plato's theories, specifically the Theory of Forms.

Comment: About the reverse: nothing, Plato was the teacher.

Comment: See [Aristotle’s Life](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle/#AriLif): "Born in 384 B.C.E., Aristotle remained associated with the Academy until Plato’s death in 347, at which time he left for Assos, in Asia Minor. In 343, upon the request of Philip, the king of Macedon, Aristotle left Lesbos for Pella, the Macedonian capital, before returning to Athens for the second and final time, in 335. In Athens, Aristotle set up his own school ."